# Sharing a drive that shows up under /media

Tags: networking, samba

When I installed Ubuntu 14.04 I made a fresh install on a new drive.  The old drive became my data drive and shows up under /media.  I have tried unsuccessfully to share this second drive on my in-house local network. It appears  All the samba settings are correct and work for the main drive, but not the drive that installs under the /media folder as a device. I have given Adm  privileges to the ownership. The drive shows as a shared drive in all the settings, It's correct in the smb.comf file but still cannot be accessed. I get the message `Unable to access location. Failed to mount Windows share: Permission denied.`  Yet permissions were established in the share. 
Can anyone help figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu isn't capable of changing permissions on NTFS drives.  You could format it as EXT4.

I think there is a program which allows you to emulate changing permissions for NTFS drives, but my google-fu has failed me.

Comment: The drive in question is not an NTFS drive. It's an EXT4 drive that formerly was the boot drive for an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS install.